# SQL query with conditions and GROUP BY inside CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

users:

```
+------------+-----------+
| user_id    | company   |
+------------+-----------+
| 1          | Apple     |
| 2          | Apple     |
| 3          | Microsoft |
+------------+-----------+
```

sessions:

```
+------------+---------+
| session_id | user_id |
+------------+---------+
| 1          | 1       |
| 2          | 3       |
| 3          | 1       |
+------------+---------+
```

I want to query both tables in one query and have an output that looks like this:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| company    | totalUsers   | activeUsers  |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| Apple      | 2            | 1            |
| Microsoft  | 1            | 1            |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

with a query like this:

```
SELECT users.company, COUNT(users.user_id) as totalUsers, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN COUNT(sessions.session_id) > 0 
                          then sessions.user_id end)) as activeUsers 
FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sessions ON users.user_id = sessions.user_id 
GROUP BY users.company_name
```

The query throws errors. I know that the activeUsers count is wrong but can't figure out how to organise it. Also, by adding the LEFT OUTER JOIN i get the wrong result for totalUsers, i think it starts counting sessions as users

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't nest COUNT functions like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT users.company, 
       COUNT(users.user_id) as totalUsers,
       COUNT(s.user_id) as activeUsers
FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
   SELECT DISTINCT user_id
   FROM sessions
) AS s ON users.user_id = s.user_id 
GROUP BY users.company
```

**How it works:**

- If `s.user_id` is null, then there is no entry for this user in the `sessions` table, and `COUNT` will skip this user.
- If `s.user_id` is not null, then `COUNT` will count this user *just once* (because derived table `s` contains a *distinct* list of users).

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dac2/2)

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - my apologies had a typo

Comment: It might be too late to ask this but if i also wanted to count total sessions by company how would i do this?

I tried adding
`COUNT(s2.session_id) as totalSessions`
to the first `SELECT` and
`LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT sessions.session_id, sessions.user_id FROM sessions) AS s2 ON users.user_id = s2.user_id`

however it breaks the other counts

Answer (score 0):

If you need some easy to follow query, I'd suggest to use CTE (with clause), so you can calculate active and total users separately and then combine 2 parts:

```
With 

 total_users as ( SELECT company, count(user_id) as tot_usr FROM users)

,active_users as (SELECT company, count(user_id) as act_usr FROM users where user_id in (select user_id from sessions))


SELECT 
 t.company
, t.tot_usr
, a.act_ust
FROM total_users T 
 left outer join active_users A on t.company = a.company
```